# Performing serial communication in constructor to initialize an object

Tags: c#, object-oriented, dependency-injection, constructors

I have a class `UnitInfo` which represents a collection of unit information with methods to get the unit information in a structured way, such as a specific encoding, etc. This unit info consists of information which must be read from the unit via serial port communication. The constructor of the class is given the serial number, which cannot be queried from the unit, and an instance serial communication interface, which it then uses to query the unit for the information:

```
public class UnitInfo {
    public int SerialNumber { get; }
    public int InternalMemorySize { get; }
    // And more properties...

    public UnitInfo(ISerialCom serialCom, int serialNumber) {
        SerialNumber = serialNumber;
        InternalMemorySize = serialCom.GetInternalMemorySize();
        // More serial communication to set more properties
    }

    // Get methods to retrieve all the unit information in a specific encoding
    // i.e a collection of bytes.
}
```

From my browsing SO and Google, I understand that it is usually okay to do work in a constructor, but I've yet to find an example of performing communcation via serial, GPIB, etc. in a constructor. I'm also thinking this may be a violation of the Dependency Injection principle as the class is dependent upon some implementation of an interface to initialize itself; is it better to pass all of the unit information to the class?

Comment: I did some googling for the ISerialCom interface, and found nothing. Is this interface specific to your application? Is this communication pretty fast, or do you expect lag time?

Comment: @GregBurghardt this is an interface specific to my application. Communication is pretty fast, and it should the time to query all the required properties would certainly be under one second

Comment: I would expect a constructor to finish initialization in well under 1 second. Milliseconds at most. I think if this communication is happening in milliseconds, then there is nothing wrong with this design.

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes, it is only sending/receiving a few dozen bytes at a fairly high baud rate

Comment: This class certainly isn't a violation of the DI principle. You are providing it with an implementation of `ISerialCom`, which is presumably an interface. So you are injecting its dependency, rather than it being tightly coupled to that dependency by eg performing a `new SerialCom()` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design is perfectly fine. Though you are communicating with external ports, it is hardware presumably plugged directly in to the computer, so communication happens quickly.

Since you are working in C#, exceptions in the constructor as a result of the user pulling the plug (literally) aren't a concern, because the Common Language Runtime is responsible for cleanup, although I would make sure the `ISerialCom` object implements `IDisposable` if you need to manage the connection (but that's not the responsibility of this constructor).

The nice thing about accepting an object that provides this vital information is it makes constructing this object pretty bullet-proof. You can't accidentally pass the internal memory size in place of the serial number.

Answer (score 3):

## Doing work in the constructor

This is one of those things which is ultimately a matter of opinion. While your currently accepted answer is *one* opinion, it's not one that I would share, and [I'm not alone with that](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/):

> Work in the constructor such as: creating/initializing collaborators, **communicating with other services**, and logic to set up its own state removes seams needed for testing, forcing subclasses/mocks to inherit unwanted behavior.  Too much work in the constructor prevents instantiation or altering collaborators in the test.

(Emphasis mine)

However, I would not concur 100% with Misko Hevery either (different opinions...), who sees "Anything more than field assignment" as a warning sign. "Short and sweet" validation like null checks or asserting an int to be in a certain range are acceptable.

My favorite metaphor for this: *A dentist's job is not to construct a dentist's office*.

## Practical Advice

It should not be too difficult to create a `UnitInfoFactory` which is responsible for creating those `UnitInfo`s. If `UnitInfo` is very small, a static Factory method is fine, too.

You would *instantly* be able to create a `UnitInfo` with just two ints instead of having to get an implementation of `ISerialCom` somehow (disregarding the code you left out in the example of course). This is gold if you're doing unit tests, because even with a mocking framework it is still additional work to create that mock. However, even if you're not unit testing, code written to be testable tends to be cleaner than other code.

## No Violation of DI principles

However, this part here is not a matter of opinion:

> I'm also thinking this may be a violation of the Dependency Injection principle as the class is dependent upon some implementation of an interface to initialize itself.

As far as your example code goes, I could provide a mock implementation of `ISerialCom`  that always returns zero for `GetInternalMemorySize()` and it would still work. As such, your class is not "dependent upon some *implementation* of an interface", it is only dependent upon the interface itself.

I think the misunderstanding lies in the fact that the class still needs an(y) implementation to actually work, but that's not what the DI principle is about. As David Arno already mentioned in the comments, problems arise when you use `new` in the constructor.

The best mnemonic I found for this is "**new is glue**": Every time you use `new` in your code, that code is tied down to *that specific implementation*.  If you repeatedly use `new` *in constructors*, you will create *a chain of specific implementations*. And because you can't "have" an instance of a class without constructing it, you cant separate that chain.

But it seems like you're not doing that, so that's fine.

Comment: Excellent points. Accessing a hardware device in a constructor is like plugging in a new coffee pot and having hot water spray everywhere. Unintended side effects can be nasty.